# How to get a Stream of space delimited Strings by reading a file?

Tags: java, file, java-stream

I am trying to read a text file and get a stream of the words inside it. By words, I mean simply Strings that are space delimited. I know Java has `Files.lines()` method that gives a `Stream<String>` but this is a stream of lines. I wish to post-process this stream by splitting each line with space. But the following code:

```java
return Files.lines(Path.of(filename)).map((line)-> line.split(" "));
```

gives me a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to Stream<String>Java(16777235)
```

Is there some casting that I need to do here to `Stream<String>` or is there a better way to get a stream of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split` returns an array. You can use `flatMap` to wrap arrays into streams and connect them:

```
Stream<String> words = Files.lines(Path.of(filename))
    .map(line -> line.split(" "))
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream);
```

Comment: No need for two steps. Instead of `.map(line -> line.split(" ")) .flatMap(Arrays::stream)` you can use a single `.flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")))`

Comment: @Holger Sure, but I've thought that separating them makes it clearer for the person asking.

Answer (score 1):

To add more alternative to the other two answers.

```
        Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(Files.readString(Paths.get(filename)).split(" "));
```

Is an alternative way but is essentially the same thing as the others.

List list = new ArrayList<>();

```
    try{
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while(s.hasNext()){
            String string = s.next();
            list.add(string);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

This is a way that should be more efficient as the Scanner naturally reads until it hits a space.